# SOQL Query To Return Any Open Tasks Assigned To a User

Tags: soql, query, tasks

As the title suggests, I'm simply trying to return a list of open tasks for a particular user so I can mass-change owner using Dataloader.

I've worked my way to this query:

```
SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name
FROM Task
WHERE Account.Name = 'John Smith' AND isClosed = false
```

This is returning no records, however I have checked the users profile and they do have active tasks.

Interestingly, if I change the query to `isClosed = true`, it returns the list of completed tasks. However that is not what I need.

Furthermore, I've looked into Task fields and there is an "Assigned to" field that indicates to me that I am maybe using an incorrect `WHERE` clause in my query. Is there an easier identifier  to get the name or Id of whoever owns the task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are retrieving information about the related Account but that doe not mean the Owner of the Task matches the Account Name.

```
SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name
FROM Task
WHERE Owner.Name = 'John Smith'
AND isClosed = false
```

This query will return the Account information you need for any open Tasks assigned to 'John Smith'.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try, OWNER.Name='xxx' in your WHERE clause.

Thanks

Comment: This answer would be improved if you included details about why your suggestion should work, and why OP's current approach is failing (like TSmith's answer does).